# Disable a button dynamically created

Tags: jquery, ajax, button

I have a button created in ajax event (I call some data and I create a button at the end).

How do I disable it?

I try:

```
$(document).on("click", ".sendLead", function(event) {
    $(".sendLead").disabled = true;
    some code...
```

but it does not work !

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disabled` is a boolean attribute that you have to set with the `prop()` method or the `attr()` method on your element. So simply try:

```js
$('.sendLead').click(function(event) {
  $(".sendLead").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sendLead">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `attr` function in jQuery

replace

```
$(".sendLead").disabled = true;
```

with

if you are using jQuery 1.6 or prior use

```
$('.sendLead').attr('disabled',true);
```

or

```
$('.sendLead').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

after jQuery 1.6 use

```
$('.sendLead').prop('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", ".sendLead", function(event) {
     $(".sendLead").prop("disabled", true);
```